# Cannot connect to Container-optimized-os (running a spring-boot application using docker) using external ip

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a Google compute instance with Container-optimized-OS image.

I have configured the firewall to allow http and https.

I am using the docker image with spring boot application which connects to cloudsql. When I use run command on compute engine instance ssh, i.e. (docker run --rm name), the spring boot app is started successfully.

When I try to access the webservices through compute engine instance external ip, it is not working.

I went through a different question, and found that I should try using the sudo wget http://localhost command on the instance cli first and if it is good then everything should be good. But I am getting a connection refused message on 127.0.0.1:80.

I also tried the command to open port from Container optimized OS, I.E.
sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT , nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the correct solution by your help (John Hanley and Cyac). 
I am combining both solutions in order to help the next person facing this.

As told by John, by default Spring boot uses port 8080, not 80 and as specified by Cyac you need to specify the port as 80 explicitly in application.properties file using

```
server.port=80
```

1. Make sure you expose the port 80 in docker image
2. On GCP Contaier optimized OS make sure you have allowed traffic for HTTP and HTTPs
3. Run command:

   ```sh
   sudo iptables -w -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
4. Run docker using:

   ```sh
   docker run -p 80:80 SPRING_IMAGE.
   ```

   Where SPRING_IMAGE is the name of the docker image with spring boot build.
5. Test by using curl http://localhost/ENDPOINT_NAME , e.g. http://localhost/shops/all

Answer (score 2):

The default port for Spring Boot is 8080 and not 80.

Run this command inside the instance container to see what ports are in LISTENING state:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

You can redirect port 80 to port 8080 with this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Note: This `iptables` command only redirects port 80 to 8080 on network interfaces. This has no effect for `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

For Google Compute Engine instances you do not need to enable ports using `iptables`. This is done via Google VPC firewall rules. You can use both but make sure you understand exactly what you are configuring and the side effects.

Note: Your Spring Boot application needs to listen on `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost`. The last two are internal only addresses. `0.0.0.0` means listen on all network interfaces.

Note: Do not use `sudo` in front of `wget`. This is not necessary.

Comment: ```shell
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```
I can see that this command works on Container-Optimized-OS and I wonder why I cannot see the port 80 there, even after running the command specified in the documentation link: [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/firewall).

Any suggestions on how to allow http traffic?

Comment: As of now I only see the following output:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      319/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      343/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37793         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      321/containerd      
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      319/systemd-resolve

Comment: @nayandhabarde I just corrected my answer. The `netstat` command should be executed inside the container to see which port Spring Boot is listening on.

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm what port your springboot application uses - if it's 8080 or 80. This depends on what you have configured inside **application.properties** file. This port is referred to as **ContainerPort** in below steps.

1. Execute `docker run <image-name>:<tag>`. This will run the image and show container logs on the console. If there is something wrong with your spring-boot app, the logs will show that and the container will shutdown. Press `Ctrl+C` to stop the container and return to shell.
2. If there is no error in step 1 run `docker run -d -p<HostPort>:<ContainerPort> <image-name>:<tag>`. Here **HostPort** is any free port in your GCP host VM and **ContainerPort** is the port used by your spring boot application within the container. Option `d` starts your container in detached mode.
3. Run `docker ps` and make sure that the container started in step 2 is running. It may not run if there is an error - for example if the **HostPort** you specified is already in use.
4. If step 3 shows that the container is running, execute `curl http://localhost:<HostPort>/<End-Point-Path>`. Here **End-Point-Path** is a valid path to a working endpoint within the container. If the endpoint is correct you should see expected result from the spring-boot app in the console.
5. Navigate to **Google Cloud Console -> VPC network -> Firewall rules** and add a firewall rule to open **HostPort** on your GCP VM.
6. Access your endpoint via the VM's external IP with URL - `http://<VM-External-IP>:<HostPort>/<End-Point-Path>`

Unless there is an application issue with your spring-boot app these steps should get you going.